# Why did Uniswap abandon Vyper?

Tags: contract-design, dapps, uniswap

Uniswap V1 was coded in Vyper.

They switched to Solidity for the V2.

Why is it so?
Was vyper lacking functionalities that would have made impossible to code Uniswap V2 with it?

Answer (score 5):

There were [several](https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/10/vyper-preliminary-security-review/) [audits](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/10/24/watch-your-language-our-first-vyper-audit/) that found important issues. Both audits won't recommend vyper for use in production. Then the Ethereum Foundation [decided](https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/08/update-on-the-vyper-compiler/) to support an alternative implementation in rust, while the original python implementation continues development independently.

Vyper is an interesting alternative to solidity but the lack of a production ready compiler makes it a difficult choice.

Comment: While this information was correct by the time, it is incorrect now. Vyper is used in the production by Yearn and Curve at least, both multibillion dollar projects https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/python/